# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'range' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, range

Write a Python program to find numbers between 120 and 200 which are divisible by 7 and multiples of 5 without using a "for loop".

I tried to work it out this way...

```
x = range(120, 200)
if x % 7 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
    print(x)
```

But rather I do get this error. What could I be missing out?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\skillshare-code\if else statements\4.py", line 
    11, in <module>
if x % 7 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'range' and 'int'
```

Comment: You need to loop through all the values in `x` but you're not allowed to use the `for` construct

Comment: "What could I be missing out?" `%` only works on single numbers, you're trying to use it on a range of numbers.

Comment: Most operations don't automatically loop themselves if you give them an iterable object.

Comment: "which are divisible by 7 and multiples of 5": your teacher has a sense of humour (and mindscrew :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I was staring at that for so long thinking, does he just mean 35? haha

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not allowed to use the `for` construct, you can accomplish this with the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) method:

```
valid_nums = filter(lambda x: x % 35 == 0, range(120, 200))
```

Note that the problem is not asking you to print the numbers but rather "find" them which means to create some form of list or collection of the valid values

PS: I did `x % 35 == 0` because "divisble by" and "multiples of" means the same thing and so 35 is from `7*5`.

PPS: `filter` returns a filter object which is a generator. You will need to convert that to a list if you want to view the list by doing `list(valid_nums)`. You don't need to do the conversion if you just need to iterate through the values and use them for something else since the generator will work just fine for that

Comment: that's probably what the (evil) teacher had in mind. You could explain the 35, and also note that `filter` needs to be iterated upon (wrapping it to `list` for instance) in python 3 else it just returns a generator.

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher likes it twisted. Divisible by 7 and multiple of 5 just means divisible by both 7 and 5, so 35...

Your original code *needs* a loop. But python has built-ins that generate loops without a `for` or `while` statement (and they're much faster than `for` or `while` because they're usually using native compiled C code)

sshashank124 gave a nice answer, but it can be simplified even more by:

- choosing the proper `range` start point by "aligning" 120 on the next multiple of 35
- use a step of 35 in `range`

like this:

```
>>> list(range(((120//35)+1)*35,200,35))
[140, 175]
```

It's probably much faster because it only uses one division & multiplication, then only additions.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a list comprehension is more idiomatic for Python than `filter` (of course if you are allowed).

```
x = range(120, 200)
valid_nums = [num for num in x if num % 35 == 0]
```

Or at creation:

```
valid_nums = [num for num in range(120, 200) if num % 35 == 0]
```

Comment: but it uses a `for` loop _inside_ the list comprehension.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not a Python for loop. Internally filter also uses loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is define x as a range of numbers but that will make x a list of numbers and you will still have to go through every number to check it. Since "for loop" is not allowed, you can use a while loop or call a function recursively starting from lower limit till the passable parameter hits upper limit.

```
def func(x):
       if (condition satisfied):
            print(x)
       if x<upper_limit:
            func(x+1)
       return
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my reading the challenge was to find all the numbers in a range that were divisible by 7 but not by five.

That's very different from simply reducing the problem to `x % 35`. Still, creating a list comprehension was the answer.

Here is what worked for me:

```
x = range(2000, 3201)
num = [n for n in x if n % 7 == 0 and n % 5 != 0]
```

Once this is done, simply `print(num)` and you have your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle array elements at once, you need to use a numpy array instead of a normal list.

```py
import numpy as np
A1 = list(range(120 , 200)) 
A2 = np.array(range(120 , 200))   

print(A1[(((A2 % 7) == 0) +0) != 0]) # This will produce an error, as it is a list
print(A2[(((A2 % 7) == 0) +0) != 0]) # this will work
```

Output

```
[126 133 140 147 154 161 168 175 182 189 196]
```